# What is the relationship between the variance of weekly data and the variance of monthly data?

Tags: time-series, variance

Assume

- 1 month = 4 weeks
- Variance = VARP function of Google Sheet = $\Sigma^{n}_{i=1}(x_i - \mu)^2 / n$

I have sample data, the number of items sold on a specific week and in a specific month.
The data of Month 1 is the sum of the data of Week 1-4, Month 2 = Sum of Week 5-8 and Month 3 = Sum of Week 9-12.

If I calculate the variance of weekly data, it's 21.41.
On the other hand, the variance of monthly data is 6.22.

I would like to calculate variances in this way above.

Is there any relationship between the variance of weekly data and the variance of monthly data in general?
If there is, what is it?

[image: Sample data]